# MKOverlayRenderer scales down overlay image

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkoverlay

I have a map application that allows user to draw shapes on the map as below:
[image]

This is a UIView, on top of the MKMapView and I've created the the shape using UIBezierPath.What I want to do is to convert this UIView to an MKMapOverlayRendrer.

That's how I've done that:

1. Subclassed MKMapOverlay, I've called it RWSelectedAreaOverlay:
   .h file:

   ```
   @interface RWSelectedAreaOverlay : NSObject <MKOverlay>

   @property(readonly, nonatomic) MKMapRect boundingMapRect;

   @property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

   // I'm converting the UIView to UIImage and use this property to stick to it.
   @property(readonly, strong, nonatomic) UIImage *overlayImage;


   - (id)initWithBoundingMapRect:(MKMapRect)aMapRect coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)aCoordinate
         image:(UIImage *)anImage;

   @end
   ```

and this is how I'm adding overlay to my MapView:

```
MKMapRect mapRect = [self.mapView visibleMapRect];

CLLocationCoordinate2D overlayCenter = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;

RWSelectedAreaOverlay *overlay = [[RWSelectedAreaOverlay alloc] initWithBoundingMapRect:mapRect
                                                                coordinate:overlayCenter
                                                                image:overlayImage];


[self.mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
```

Then I implemented `- (MKOverlayRenderer *)rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay` to render my overlay on the map.

My implementation is as below:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {

    RWSelectedAreaOverlayRenderer *result = [[RWSelectedAreaOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];

    if (![overlay isKindOfClass:[RWSelectedAreaOverlay class]]) {
        return result;
    }
    if (![self.mapView isEqual:mapView]) {
        return result;
    }


    RWSelectedAreaOverlay *selectedAreaOverlay = (RWSelectedAreaOverlay *) overlay;

    UIImage *image = selectedAreaOverlay.overlayImage;



    result.imageFrame = mapView.frame;
    result.selection = image;
    return result;
}
```

My render method can successfully add the overlay to the map, but for some reasons, It's scaling it down to a very small image instead of the full size image I've created, and it shows it on top left side instead! (not even sure if you can see the image, it's very small on top left side.

[image]

Just wondering if some one can help me with this issue.

Comment: You haven't shown how RWSelectedAreaOverlayRenderer is implemented and if that class is designed to render an RWSelectedAreaOverlay, why would you need to manually update its properties in rendererForOverlay?  Also, instead of capturing what the user drew as an _image_, why not capture the _coordinates_ as they draw and then create an `MKPolygon` and render using `MKPolygonRenderer`?  All the scaling and drawing will be done for you.

Comment: @Anna  Very cool!!! I changed it to MKPolygonRenderer and it started working! I wish you had put it as answer so I could mark it as answer.